# How to attach counter variable on field in twig file?

Tags: html, symfony, for-loop, twig

I make a table in twig file and i want to populate data through loop but my fields name same so i want to attach a counter variable along each field name,how i do this?

Here is my code:

```
<div id="table">
    <table class="table table-bordered">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th style="text-align:left; width:120px;">Item</th>
            <th style="text-align:left; width:200px;">Description</th>
            <th style="width:100px;">Unit Cost</th>
            <th style="text-align:right; width:60px;">Qty</th>
            <th style="text-align:left; width:100px;">Tax</th>
            <th style="text-align:left; width:100px;">Tax</th>
            <th style="text-align:right; width:100px;">Line Total</th>
       </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    {% for items in itemdata %}         
     <tr>        
     <td colspan=7 width=800>
     <select class="items" name="items" style="width:127px; float:left;" id="items"><option value="1" selected="selected" disabled="disabled"></option></select>
     <textarea name="description" id="description" class="description" style="float:left; display: block; height: 30px; width:209px; border-radius:0px; margin: -1px 1px 0;">{{ items.description }}</textarea>
     <input type="text" name="unitprice" id="unitprice" class="unitprice" value="{{ items.unitPrice }}" style="float:left; display:block; height:30px; width:106px; border-radius:0px; margin:-1px -1px 0;">
     <input type="text" name="quantity" id="quantity" class="quantity" value="{{ items.quantity }}" style="float:left; display: block; height: 30px; width:64px; border-radius:0px; margin: -1px 1px 0;">
     <select name="firsttax" id="firsttax" style=" float:left; display: block; height: 31px; width:106px; border-radius:0px; margin: -2px -1px 0;"><option value="1" selected="selected" ></option></select>
     <select name="secondtax" id="secondtax" style="float:left; display: block; height: 31px; width:107px; border-radius:0px; margin: -2px 0px 0;"><option value="1" selected="selected"></option></select>
     <input type="text" name="linetotal" id="linetotal" class="linetotal" value="{{ items.linetotal }}" placeholder="0.00" readonly style="float:right; display: block; height: 31px; width:107px; border-radius:0px; background-color: #F0F0F0; text-align:right; margin: -31px -1px 0;">       
     </td>
     </tr>
     <input type="hidden" id="itemscounter" name="itemscounter" value=""/>
     {% endfor %}
```

My fields name same here is screenshot:

[image]

How to change field names like description,description2,description3,description4 and so on.....

Where

```
itemscounter value = number of rows
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're simply looking for its index in the loop:

```
<textarea name="description{{ loop.index }}">
```

[Here's the docs.](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/tags/for.html#the-loop-variable)

Comment: And if you want itemscounter to show the no. items it can be placed outside the for loop:
<input type="hidden" id="itemscounter" name="itemscounter" value="{{ itemdata | length }}"/>